# Extract a duration from character in R

Tags: r, date, character

I'm currently facing an issue with a dataset that I need to analyze. Here is a sample of these data :

```
      session_id    individ_id  colony     species           year_tracked
1 12141_2009-07-01 GBT_FP96194 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2009_10
2 12141_2010-07-18 GBT_FP96235 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2010_11
3 12143_2009-07-01 GBT_FC14766 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2009_10
4 12143_2010-07-18 GBT_FR77883 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2010_12
5 12144_2009-07-01 GBT_FP05030 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2009_10
6 12145_2009-07-01 GBT_FA82356 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2009_10
```

I need to create a new column with the number of years tracked, which in that case would be :

```
2010-2009 --> 1
2011-2010 --> 1
2010-2009 --> 1
2012-2010 --> 2
2010-2009 --> 1
2010-2009 --> 1
```

The `year_tracked` column is a  `character` class. Maybe a function that take the first 4 character of the cell and the last two and convert it to date would work but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Can you show the logic for the expected output

Comment: just updated it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(year_tracked2 = str_replace(year_tracked, "_", "_20")) %>% 
    separate(year_tracked2, into = c('year1', 'year2'), convert = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(n = year2 - year1) %>%
    select(-year1, -year2)
#       session_id  individ_id    colony         species year_tracked n
#1 12141_2009-07-01 GBT_FP96194 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2009_10 1
#2 12141_2010-07-18 GBT_FP96235 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2010_11 1
#3 12143_2009-07-01 GBT_FC14766 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2009_10 1
#4 12143_2010-07-18 GBT_FR77883 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2010_12 2
#5 12144_2009-07-01 GBT_FP05030 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2009_10 1
#6 12145_2009-07-01 GBT_FA82356 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2009_10 1
```

---

Or an easier option is to replace the `_` with `:20` and just do an `eval`uation

```
library(purrr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(n = lengths(map(str_replace(year_tracked, "_", ":20"),
           ~ eval(parse(text = .x))))- 1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(session_id = c("12141_2009-07-01", "12141_2010-07-18", 
"12143_2009-07-01", "12143_2010-07-18", "12144_2009-07-01", "12145_2009-07-01"
), individ_id = c("GBT_FP96194", "GBT_FP96235", "GBT_FC14766", 
"GBT_FR77883", "GBT_FP05030", "GBT_FA82356"), colony = c("Eynhallow", 
"Eynhallow", "Eynhallow", "Eynhallow", "Eynhallow", "Eynhallow"
), species = c("Northern fulmar", "Northern fulmar", "Northern fulmar", 
"Northern fulmar", "Northern fulmar", "Northern fulmar"), year_tracked = c("2009_10", 
"2010_11", "2009_10", "2010_12", "2009_10", "2009_10")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here with a bit of regex:
first extract the first year with four number `str_extract(.,"[0-9]{4}")`, then extract the second year `str_extract(.,"(?<=_)[0-9]{2}")`, transform it to the format YYYY by adding `20`, and then subtract the two

```
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

from <- df$year_tracked %>%
  str_extract(.,"[0-9]{4}") %>%
  as.numeric()

to <- df$year_tracked %>%
  str_extract(.,"(?<=_)[0-9]{2}") %>%
  paste0("20",.) %>%
  as.numeric()

result <- to - from

[1] 1 1 1 2 1 1
```

---

data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "      session_id    individ_id  colony     species           year_tracked
 12141_2009-07-01 GBT_FP96194 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2009_10
 12141_2010-07-18 GBT_FP96235 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2010_11
 12143_2009-07-01 GBT_FC14766 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2009_10
 12143_2010-07-18 GBT_FR77883 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2010_12
 12144_2009-07-01 GBT_FP05030 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2009_10
 12145_2009-07-01 GBT_FA82356 Eynhallow Northern fulmar      2009_10",header = T)
```